# Multiple instances of Setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a little problem with my code.

I have it setup so that by default, a rotating fadeIn fadeOut slider is auto playing, and when a user clicks on a li, it will jump to that 'slide' and pause the slider for x amount of time.

The problem i have is that if the user clicks on multiple li's very fast, then it will run color1() multiple times with will start colorInterval multiple times. This gives a undesired effect.

So what i need help with, is figuring out how to reset my code each time a li is clicked, so whenever ColorClick is clicked, i want to make sure that there are no other instances of colorInterval before i start a new one.

Thanks in advance!

=================================

edit: 
I now have another problem, i believe that i fixed the clearInterval problem, but now if you look at var reset, you'll see that it runs color1() each time a li is clicked, which runs multiple intervals, so i need to delete the previous instance of color1() each time it is called, to make sure that it doesnt repeat any code inside multiple times. So when a li is clicked delete any instances of color1()

or

i need that instead of running color1 in var reset, i will go straight to colorInterval instead of running color1() for each li clicked,

so run colorInterval after x amount of time in var reset.

```
function color1() {
  var pass = 0;
  var counter = 2;
  var animationSpeed = 500;

  var $colorContent = '.color-container-1 .color-content-container'

  var $li = '.color-container-1 .main-color-container li'

  $($li).on('click', function() {
    colorClick($(this));
  });

  function colorClick($this) {
    var $getClass = $this.attr("class").split(' ');
    var $whichNumber = $getClass[0].substr(-1);
    var $Parent = '.color-container-1 ';

    pass = 1;
    $($colorContent).fadeOut(0);
    $($colorContent + '-' + $whichNumber).fadeIn(animationSpeed);

    var reset = setTimeout(function() {
      clearTimeout(reset);
      pass = 0;
      color1();
    }, 10000);
  }



  var colorInterval = setInterval(function() {

    if (pass > 0) {
      clearInterval(colorInterval);
      return; //stop here so that it doesn't continue to execute below code
    }

    $($colorContent).fadeOut(0);
    $(($colorContent + '-' + counter)).fadeIn(animationSpeed);
    ++counter

    if (counter === $($colorContent).length + 1) {
      counter = 1;
    }

  }, 7000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just clear the interval inside of the click event.

```
var colorInterval;
$($li).on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(colorInterval);
    colorClick($(this));
});

//Your other code

colorInterval = setInterval(function() {
//Rest of your code
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it, what is happening is, var reset runs color1() each time it is clicked, so for each li click click1() will run, which will start multiple intervals. So i need a way to call color1() in var reset only once, and delete the previous instance of color1() if the li is clicked more than once.@joe

Comment: I agree with the principle stated here. You need to store the currently running interval somewhere that all your code can see it, then, when you want to start another interval, check that variable, and if it's not null, then clear the existing interval.

Comment: This make sense, but still leaves me with the problem of after i click an li, var reset runs which sets pass = 0; which allow colorInterval to run, but i need a way to restart colorInterval. what i am doing now, is running color1() again with make many instances of colorInterval, which runs all my code multiple times, even if i clear the previous colorInterval, my code is still running multiple times. So i need to start colorInterval in var reset, by either clearing all instances of color1() or, calling colorInterval, which im not sure how to do. @frodo2975

Comment: Instead of calling color1() again you could wrap colorInterval = setInterval... into a function and call that on reset.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks so much, and everyone else that provided answers! @Joe

Answer (score 0):

One thing play with is jQuery animations have a pseudo class selector `:animated` when animation is in progress

```
if(!$('.your-slide-class:animated').length){
   // do next animation
}
```